# Find substring in string but only if whole words?

Tags: python, search, string, substring

What is an elegant way to look for a string within another string in Python, but only if the substring is within whole words, not part of a word?

Perhaps an example will demonstrate what I mean:

```
string1 = "ADDLESHAW GODDARD"
string2 = "ADDLESHAW GODDARD LLP"
assert string_found(string1, string2)  # this is True
string1 = "ADVANCE"
string2 = "ADVANCED BUSINESS EQUIPMENT LTD"
assert not string_found(string1, string2)  # this should be False
```

How can I best write a function called string_found that will do what I need? I thought perhaps I could fudge it with something like this:

```
def string_found(string1, string2):
   if string2.find(string1 + " "):
      return True
   return False
```

But that doesn't feel very elegant, and also wouldn't match string1 if it was at the end of string2. Maybe I need a regex? *(argh regex fear)*

Answer (score 51):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and the word boundary special character `\b` (highlight by me):

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so **the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character**. Note that `\b` is defined as the boundary between `\w` and `\W`, so the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the `UNICODE` and `LOCALE` flags. Inside a character range, `\b` represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

```
def string_found(string1, string2):
    if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2):
        return True
    return False
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/uBGkBVo0)

---

If word boundaries are only whitespaces for you, you could also get away with pre- and appending whitespaces to your strings:

```
def string_found(string1, string2):
    string1 = " " + string1.strip() + " "
    string2 = " " + string2.strip() + " "
    return string2.find(string1)
```

Comment: Up-voted for the theoretical suggestion. Your script, OTOH, will not work. `'\b'` is the escape sequence for the backspace (`'\x08'`) character. I would suggest `r'\b%s\b' % (re.escape(string1))` as the first parameter to `re.search()` in stead. In fact, that whole function could be reduced to `return re.search(r'\b%s\b' % (re.escape(string1)), string2) is not None`

Comment: @Walter: Not sure about `\b`. It is said: *Inside a **character range**, `\b` represents the backspace character, ...* It works for me at least. But yes, string substitution is nice too :)

Comment: when \b is inside a character range [a-z0-9\b]...? \b should work, and did in the very brief test I did

Comment: @Walter: Your `r'\b%s\b' % (re.escape(string1))` has identical results to Felix's `r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b"`; side note: the extra parens in yours aren't useful, as they don't represent a tuple of length one.  Though `if ...: return True; else: return False` is also a big pet peeve of mine.

Comment: In my use case I have many cases in which string_found() return False. To make it way faster for False cases add a test for string1 in string2 before running the expensive re.search(): 
     def string_found(string1, string2):
        if string1 in string2 and if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2): ...

Answer (score 17):

The simplest and most pythonic way, I believe, is to break the strings down into individual words and scan for a match:

```
string = "My Name Is Josh"
substring = "Name"

for word in string.split():
    if substring == word:
        print("Match Found")
```

For a bonus, here's a oneliner:

```
any(substring == word for word in string.split())
```

Comment: I like this one as it most closely matches the `grep -w` in unix

Comment: Love this python approach. Works and was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The true one-line is `if word in string.split()`

Comment: Punctuation messes this up, for example: `string = "What is your name?"; substring = "name"; substring in string.split()` -> `False`. Using regex word bounds is more thorough.

Comment: @vr00n Actually, [the regex word bound answer](/a/4155064/4518341) is closer. For example, look at punctuation, like I mentioned above: `grep -qw "name" <<< "What is your name?"` -> true. (At least for GNU grep. I'm not sure about other implementations. `-w` isn't specificed in POSIX.)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way to do it without a regex (as requested) assuming that you want any whitespace to serve as a word separator.

```
import string

def find_substring(needle, haystack):
    index = haystack.find(needle)
    if index == -1:
        return False
    if index != 0 and haystack[index-1] not in string.whitespace:
        return False
    L = index + len(needle)
    if L < len(haystack) and haystack[L] not in string.whitespace:
        return False
    return True
```

And here's some [demo code](http://codepad.org/ipOvXNwH) (codepad is a great idea: Thanks to Felix Kling for reminding me)

Comment: Just make sure to "save" the codepad pastes, so they don't expire.  (I include a link back in a codepad comment, just for my own notes later, too.)

Comment: For those who want to ensure that punctuation as well as white space is considered a valid whole word delimiter... modify the above code as follows:

```not in (string.whitespace + string.punctuation)```

Also note this function is more than twice as efficient as the RegEx alternative proposed so...if you are using it a lot, this function is the way to go.

Comment: Fantastic solution. For 5000k rows I've got `1e-05` while with regex `0.0018`. 180 x faster.

Comment: The code is not quite correct. If there are *two* or more occurrences of the substring, the first *not* being a whole word but the second being a whole word, the code will only consider the first one and return false. One must look at all matches, and return false if none of them qualify.

Comment: Added my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41391098/212942 that builds off your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm building off [aaronasterling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155029/212942).

The problem with the above code is that it will return false when there are multiple occurrences of `needle` in `haystack`, with the second occurrence satisfying the search criteria but not the first.

Here's my version:

```
def find_substring(needle, haystack):
  search_start = 0
  while (search_start < len(haystack)):
    index = haystack.find(needle, search_start)
    if index == -1:
      return False
    is_prefix_whitespace = (index == 0 or haystack[index-1] in string.whitespace)
    search_start = index + len(needle)
    is_suffix_whitespace = (search_start == len(haystack) or haystack[search_start] in string.whitespace)
    if (is_prefix_whitespace and is_suffix_whitespace):
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using the `re`, or regex, module that should accomplish this task is:

```
import re

string1 = "pizza pony"
string2 = "who knows what a pizza pony is?"

search_result = re.search(r'\b' + string1 + '\W', string2)

print(search_result.group())
```

Comment: A site note to this answer. Regular expression is much slower than "find()" and with large text, one should consider using str.find()

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me REGEX fellows, but the simpler answer is:

```
text = "this is the esquisidiest piece never ever writen"
word = "is"
" {0} ".format(text).lower().count(" {0} ".format(word).lower())
```

The trick here is to add 2 spaces surrounding the 'text' and the 'word' to be searched, so you guarantee there will be returning only counts for the whole word and you don't get troubles with endings and beginnings of the 'text' searched.

Comment: What happens if, for example, the word word one is looking for has a non alphabet optional character surrounding or on either side of it?

For example:


    text = "this is the esquisidiest piece never ever writen."
    word = "writen"


     .notice the dot at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Chris Larson's comment, I test it and updated like below:

```py
import re

string1 = "massage"
string2 = "muscle massage gun"
try:
    re.search(r'\b' + string1 + r'\W', string2).group()
    print("Found word")
except AttributeError as ae:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def string_found(string1,string2):
    if string2 in string1 and string2[string2.index(string1)-1]==" 
    " and string2[string2.index(string1)+len(string1)]==" ":return True
    elif string2.index(string1)+len(string1)==len(string2) and 
    string2[string2.index(string1)-1]==" ":return True
    else:return False
```

Comment: It does the thing they wanted to do? Idk what else you want

Comment: We try to give detail in our answers so they can be understood by the OP as well as anyone who lands on this page with a similar question and potentially a different level of understanding. Welcome to Stack, though, you might find this helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer