# python check pattern in string

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Check If Word Is In A String.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string)

i have a string which is a url e.g.

```
my_url = "http://mysite.com/somefolder/somefile"
```

I want check if "somefolder" is in the `my_url` file

how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
if "/somefolder/" in my_url:
    #whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print 'somefolder' in my_url
```

OR

```
print my_url.index('somefolder')
```

Comment: Warning: the second one raises a `ValueError` if it's not there.

Comment: And, `print(my_url.find('somefolder') != -1)`

Comment: Sure, thanx - i simply gave several variants, regex also can be used to find particular word(or pattern) in text