# Check If Word Is In A String errors

Tags: python

Using the following from [Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string)

```
>>> def findWholeWord(w):
...     return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
... 
>>> findWholeWord('seek')('those who seek shall find')  
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x22c1828>
>>> findWholeWord('seek') 
<built-in method search of _sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x22b8190>
>>> findWholeWord('seek')('those who seek shall find')  
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x22c1828>
>>> findWholeWord('seek')('those who shall find')
```

Is this an error or this should be the result?

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x22c1828>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That match object is the result, and from that you have access to some more functions like

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__'
, '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__'
, '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__','end', 'endpos'
, 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 'lastindex', 'pos', 're'
, 'regs', 'span', 'start', 'string']
```

so on the returned object you can for example do `.span()` to get the start and end index of the word you are looking for.

Comment: To get string, that satisfy full regex, `.group(0)` can be used. And to get only the word in your case, `.group(1)`. This will return string, that satisfy first ().

Comment: i could use that too in further development of the app. tnx

Answer (score 3):

This is a funny piece of code, but in python finding a word in a string is actually much simpler. You don't even need a function for this:

```
 if some_word in some_str.split():
      ....
```

To find just substrings rather than whole words, omit the `split` part:

```
print 'word' in 'funny swordfish'.split()  # False
print 'word' in 'funny swordfish'          # True
```

Comment: well that's what i need not to find them, that's why i used regexp for full match. i keep it in mind for second solution tnx

Comment: @badc0re: you've lost me there. If you want it to return True, just  skip the "split" part. `if substr in somestr` will return True for "work" and "working".