# What is the python equivalent of strpos($elem,"text") !== false)

Tags: php, python-2.7, strpos

What is the python equivalent of:

```
if (strpos($elem,"text") !== false) {
    // do_something;  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string

Comment: Thanks for your ninja quick response.  However I recieve this error when using .find: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: is there a module i should import to use the .find syntax

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## returns -1 when not found:

```
pos = haystack.find(needle)
pos = haystack.find(needle, offset)
```

## raises ValueError when not found:

```
pos = haystack.index(needle)
pos = haystack.index(needle, offset)
```

To simply test if a substring is in a string, use:

```
needle in haystack
```

which is equivalent to the following PHP:

```
strpos(haystack, needle) !== FALSE
```

From http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.strpos/

Comment: thank you for the solution. just to clarify i used `if needle in haystack:`

Comment: I fell in love with `needle in haystack`. Coming from PHP, Python code is so human readable...

Answer (score 4):

```
if elem.find("text") != -1:
    do_something
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am using. But i receive the following error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: I think you are searching into a object, not into a string. If you want to search a string into a object(w/ strings), you should use a loop. Check this and update it to your code: `if "this is string example....wow!!!".find("exam") != -1:
        print "works";`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 0):

Is python is really pretty that code using "in":

```
in_word = 'word'
sentence = 'I am a sentence that include word'
if in_word in sentence:
    print(sentence + 'include:' + word)
    print('%s include:%s' % (sentence, word))
```

last 2 prints do the same, you choose.