# Find single or multiple words in string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to code a script that will find a single word or a string composed of multiple single words in a given string. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320179/1391441) which looks very much what I'd need, but I can't really understand how it works.

Using the code provided in the answer mentioned above, I have this:

```
import re

def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

st1 = 'those who seek shall find'
st2 = 'swordsmith'

print findWholeWord('seek')(st1)          # -> <match object>
print findWholeWord('these')(st1)         # -> None
print findWholeWord('THOSE')(st1)         # -> <match object>
print findWholeWord('seek shall')(st1)    # -> <match object>
print findWholeWord('word')(st2)          # -> None
```

This function returns either something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x94393e0>` (when the word(s) were found) or `None` (when they weren't) and I'd like the function to return instead either `True` or `False` if the word(s) were found or not, respectively.
Since I'm not clear on how the function is working, I'm not sure how I'd do that.

I've never seen a function being called passing two variables (?), ie: `findWholeWord(word)(string)`, what is this doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if findWholeWord('seek')(st1) == None:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Or:

```
if findWholeWord('seek')(st1): #this is evaluated 'True'
        #do something
else:
        #there is no search match, do something else
```

Or:

```
import re

def findWholeWord(w, string):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if pattern.search(string):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: First: I didn't downvote (I don't understand users who downvote and don't explain why, so I upvoted your answer). Your first answer would work but it's a bit hackish. The second answer works but I'm still left wondering how is the double `()()` working. Your third answer is more clear to me and it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel I downvoted because it didn't provide an answer to your questions and it was just a block of code with no explanation

Answer (score 1):

re is the regular expression module.  `findWholeWord` creates a regular expression object that will match the *word* (pattern) you pass it.  `findWholeWord` returns a function; the search method of the regular expression object - notice the absence of the '()' at the end of the return statement.

```
import re
def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

>>> search = findWholeWord('seek')
>>> print search
<built-in method search of _sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x032F70A8>
>>>
```

`re.search` returns a match object if the pattern is found or None if it is not.  match objects evaluate to True.

```
>>> search = findWholeWord('seek')
>>> print search
<built-in method search of _sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x032F70A8>
>>> 
>>> match = search('this string contains seek')
>>> print match, bool(match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x032FDC20> True
>>> match = search('this string does not contain the word you are looking for')
>>> print match, bool(match)
None False
>>>
```

In your example, `findWholeWord('seek')(st1)` is calling the search method of a regular expression that matches `seek' and passing it the string `st1`.

```
>>> st1 = 'those who seek shall find'
>>> match = search(st1)
>>> print match, bool(match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x032FDC20> True
>>> match = findWholeWord('seek')(st1)
>>> print match, bool(match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x032FDC60> True
>>>
```

Comment: Answers this question `I've never seen a function being called passing two variables (?), ie: findWholeWord(word)(string), what is this doing?`