# Do not match if word appears in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a url, and I want it to NOT match if the word 'season' is contained in the url. Here are two examples:

```
CONTAINS SEASON, DO NOT MATCH
'http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/episodes?this=1&season=7&ref_=tt_eps_sn_7'

DOES NOT CONTAIN SEASON, MATCH
'http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/
```

Here is what I have so far, but I'm afraid the `.+` will match everything until the end. What would be the correct regex to use here?

```
r'http://imdb.com/title/tt(\d)+/.+^[season].+'
```

Comment: does the string only contain the url?

Comment: what is wrong with [`if word in mystring:`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5319942/1959948)?

Comment: Look-ahead with `(?=.*season)` to detect it (or `(?!.*season)` to ensure it doesn't exist).

Comment: @Dalorzo: the only difference i see is that this answer doesnt't take account of the word boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
urls='''\
http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/episodes?this=1&season=7&ref_=tt_eps_sn_7
http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/'''

import re

print re.findall(r'^(?!.*\bseason\b)(.*)', urls, re.M)
# ['http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/']
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use whole words inside of character classes, you have to use a **Negative Lookahead**.

```
>>> s = '''
http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/episodes?this=1&season=7&ref_=tt_eps_sn_7
http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/
http://imdb.com/title/tt1111111/episodes?this=2
http://imdb.com/title/tt0123456/episodes?this=1&season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1'''
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\bhttp://imdb.com/title/tt(?!\S+\bseason)\S+', s)
# ['http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/', 'http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/episodes?this=2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lokahead just after to `tt\d+/`,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/episodes?this=1&season=7&ref_=tt_eps_sn_7
... http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/
... """
>>> m = re.findall(r'^http://imdb.com/title/tt\d+/(?:(?!season).)*$', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
http://imdb.com/title/tt0285331/
```

Comment: The `*` already insures that it can match even if there's nothing after the final slash.  Wrapping the last part of the regex in a group and making it optional serves no purpose.