# How would I check whether or not there is a string in an input - beginner

Tags: python

for example:

```
print ('Choose your character, Bob, a 19 year old student, or Craig, a 32 year old man')
resp = input

if ('Bob') in resp:
    print ('You have chosen Bob.')
elif ('Craig') in resp:
    print ('You have chosen Craig!')
else:
    print ('Invalid. Please check spelling')
```

please help, I am experimenting in Python ;)

Comment: Did you even Google?

Comment: Indent correctly. To call the function, append `()` after the function name: `resp = input()`. No need to surround the string literals with `(..)`.

Comment: Thanks falsetru, this is one of the first pieces of python I have coded and I am a bit lost :p

Comment: As a general note, Stack overflow usually shouldn't be your first stop when learning a new language. If you end up asking a question that can be quickly answered by [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) or [taking a tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/?hl=de-DE), you're probably going to be quickly downvoted. Especially if your question [is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319922/2615940).

Comment: thanks for the links, I wasn't aware of the Google tutorials. i won't dupe post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to actually call the input function. Secondly, your formatting will cause an `IndentationError`.

Now to answer your question. `input` will always return a string, I think you're asking how to check its value.

Try this:

```
resp = input('Choose your character, Bob, a 19 year old student, or Craig, a 32 year old man')
characters = ['Bob', 'Craig']

if resp in characters:
    print('You have chosen {}'.format(resp))
else:
    print('Invalid. Please check spelling')
```