# searching exact word in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Found the hugh bothwell answer

[Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string/31112811#31112811)

quite useful but now i want this to happen

```
 findWholeWord('object')('object test')    # -> <match object>
 findWholeWord('object')('object-group')                   # -> None
```

anybody?

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))object(?=\s|$)
```

You can use this regex with `re.findall` to check if it is there or not.

Something like

```
if re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\s))object(?=\s|$)",test_str):
    print "yes present"
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
'object(?=[\W\D\S\s]*?)'
```

This should work.