# Python check if any part of string in list

Tags: python

I have a list containing synonyms for the word 'Good' (this list here is shortened)

```
good_synonym = ['Good','good','Well','well']
```

And the program asks how the user is feeling

```
print = 'Hello, ' + name + ', How are you?'
status = raw_input('')
```

But sometimes, the user may respond to the question with "I am good" (or similar)

If the answer contains a word in the good synonym list, I want the program to reply

```
if status contains a word in good_synonym:
    print ('That is good')
else:
    print ('That is not so good')
```

## note that the first line is not real python language

But I don't know which phrase to use to do the action.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked for info before asking?

Comment: I looked around and found many references to an "any()" command but I don't fully understand its usage.

Comment: this question is barely the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could try to do this. Since you are a beginner, let's just go for something that will work - efficiency should NOT be your first consideration.

```
status = status.split() # breaks response into words
if any(s in good_synonyms for s in status):
    print('That is good')
```

Of course it won't stop your program from acting as though "not good" is a reply deserving a happy answer, but this is a programming site.

Comment: Also note @martijn's comments about using sets and preferring lower case.

Comment: Efficiency can be reached simply by using a `set` or a `frozenset` instead of a list for `good_synonyms`.

Comment: When you are learning, no new complication should be regarded as "simple" so I chose to focus on the essentials

Comment: I agree, but it's important to give the way to improvement. Learning is not the end. That's why i write a comment, rather than editing your answer.

Comment: We are both working to the same end. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a list with mixed-case words, use [*set* objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); sets make membership testing and intersection testing much easier. Store *lowercase text* only, and simply lowercase the input string:

```
good_synonym = {'good', 'well'}
# good_synonym = set(['good', 'well'])  # Python 2.6
```

Now test if the input string, lowercased and split on whitespace, is a [*disjoint set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) with [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint). If it is not a disjoint set, there is overlap between the two sets and that means at least `'good'` or `'well'` is present:

```
if not good_synonym.isdisjoint(status.lower().split()):
    print ('That is good')
else:
    print ('That is not so good')
```

Testing if a set is disjoint is efficient; it only has to test words up to the first one that is in the `good_synonym` set to return `False` quickly. You could calculate the intersection instead, but that would always test *all* words in the status to build a new set object.

Other solutions you may have seen, use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any); given a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) it too can be efficient as it would return `True` early if any of the outputs is true:

```
if any(word in good_synonym for word in status.lower().split()):
```

This, however, does all the looping and testing in Python code, while `set.isdisjoint()` is implemented entirely in C code.

Comment: This question will almost pass as a dupe, but this is a clearly different perspective for handling a case as this. Dang! +1

Comment: I seem to keep getting a syntax error with the separator between words in the set.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher: are you using Python 2.6 perhaps? Then use `set(['good', 'well'])` to create a set. The curly-brace literal syntax for sets was not introduced until Python 2.7 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

We can iterate over the good_synonyms list and check if *any* of them are present in the input string.

```
if any(synonym in status for synonym in good_synonyms):
    print('That is good')
else:
    print('That is not so good')
```

PS: To save memory, you could perhaps store the synonyms only in lower-case, as ['good', 'well'], and when you check if these are in the 'status' variable, you could just apply the .lower() on it, which just converts the entire string into lower-case, as:

```
good_synonyms = ['good', 'well']
if any(synonym in status.lower() for synonym in good_synonyms):
     print('That is good')
```

Hope this helps!

**Note**: holdenweb's answer works too, but applying the split function on status isn't really required as you can check whether a word is present in a string(provided the words in the string are separated by a space) or not using the 'in' keyword as described above.

Answer (score -1):

This is a NLP question, the following code is a simple version of detecting synonym:

```
def is_contains_synonym(sentence, synonym):
    token = sentence.split(' ')
    return len(filter(lambda x: x in synonym, token)) > 0

if is_contains_synonym(status, good_synonym):
    print ('That is good')
else:
    print ('That is not so good')
```

Answer (score -1):

A short and simple solution would be to use regular expressions for pattern matching like this:

```
import re

line = "it is good"
good_synonyms = ["good","well"]

line = line.lower()
if any(re.search(synonym,line) for synonym in good_synonyms):
    print "That is good"
else:
    print "nope"
```

The `search` function of `re` looks for a match of pattern anywhere in the string and returns a boolean which then can be used in an if statement with `any`