# searching a word in the column pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have two text columns and I would like to find whether a word from one column is present in another. I wrote the below code, which works very well, but it detects if a word is present anywhere in the string. For example, it will find "ha" in "ham". I want to use regex expression instead, but I am stuck. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string) and looked at the second answer, but I haven't been able to modify it for my purpose. I would like to do something similar.

I would appreciate help and/or any pointers

```
d = {'emp': ['abc d. efg', 'za', 'sdfadsf '], 'vendor': ['ABCD enterprise', 'za industries', '' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['clean_empy_name']=df["emp"].str.lower().str.replace('\W', ' ')

def check_subset(vendor, employee):
    s = []
    for n in employee.split():
      # n=" " + n +"[^a-zA-Z\d:]"
      if ((str(n) in vendor.lower()) & (len(str(n))>1)):
        s.append(n)
    return s

check_subset("ABC-xy 54", "54 xy")

df['emp_name_find_in_vendor'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_subset(row['vendor'],row['clean_empy_name']), axis=1)
df
```

#########update 2

i updated my dataframe as below

```
d = {'emp': ['abc d. efg', 'za', 'sdfadsf ','abc','yuma'], 'vendor': ['ABCD enterprise', 'za industries', '','Person Vue\Cisco','U OF M CONTLEARNING' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['clean_empy_name']=df["emp"].str.lower().str.replace('\W', ' ')
```

I used code provided by first answer and it fails

1. in case of `'Person Vue\Cisco'` it throws the error `error: bad escape \c`. If i remove \ in `'Person Vue\Cisco'`, code runs fine
2. in case of `'U OF M CONTLEARNING'` it return `u` and `m` when clearly they are not a match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can! It is going to be a little bit messy so let me construct in a few steps:

First, let's just create a regular expression for the single case of `check_subset("ABC-xy 54", "54 xy")`:

- We will use `re.findall(pattern, string)` to find all the occurrences of `pattern` in `string`
- The regex pattern will basically say "any of the words":

  - for the "any" we use the `|` (or) operator
  - for constructing words we need to use the parenthesis to group together... However, parenthesis `(word)` create a group that keeps track, so we could later call reuse these groups, since we are not interested we can create a non-capturing group by adding `?:` as follows: `(?:word)`

```py
import re

re.findall('(?:54)|(?:xy)', 'ABC-xy 54')
# -> ['xy', '54']
```

Now, we have to construct the `pattern` each time:

- Split into words
- Wrap each word inside a non-capturing group `(?:)`
- Join all of these groups by `|`

```py
re.findall('|'.join(['(?:'+x+')' for x in '54 xy'.split()]), 'ABC-xy 54')
```

One minor thing, since the last row's vendor is empty and you seem to want no matches (technically, the empty string matches with everything) we have to add a minor check. So we can rewrite your function to be:

```
def check_subset_regex(vendor, employee):
    if vendor == '':
        return []

    pattern = '|'.join(['(?:'+x+')' for x in vendor.lower().split(' ')])
    return re.findall(pattern, employee)
```

And then we can apply the same way:

```
df['emp_name_find_in_vendor_regex'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_subset_regex(row['vendor'],row['clean_empy_name']), axis=1)
```

One final comment is that your solution matches partial words, so employee Tom Sawyer would match "Tom" to the vendor "Atomic S.A.". The regex function I provided here will not give this as a match, should you want to do this the regex would become a little more complicated.

---

**EDIT:** Removing punctuation marks from vendors

You could either add a new column as you did with clean_employee, or simply add the removal to the function, as so (you will need to `import string` to get the `string.punctuation`, or just add in there a string with all the symbols you want to substitute):

```
def check_subset_regex(vendor, employee):
    if vendor == '':
        return []

    clean_vnd = re.sub('[' + string.punctuation + ']', '', vendor)

    pattern = '|'.join(['(?:'+x+')' for x in clean_vnd.lower().split(' ')])
    return re.findall(pattern, employee)
```

In the spirit of teaching to fish :), in regex the `[]` denote any of these characters... So `[abc]` would be the same to `a|b|c`.

So the `re.sub` line will substitute any occurrence of the `string.punctuation` (which evaluates to `` !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ``) characters by a `''` (removing them).

---

**EDIT2:** Adding the possibility of a single non-alphanumeric character at the end of each searchword:

```
def check_subset_regex(vendor, employee):
    if vendor == '':
        return []

    clean_vnd = re.sub('[' + string.punctuation + ']', '', vendor)

    pattern = '|'.join(['(?:'+x+'[^a-zA-Z0-9]?)' for x in clean_vnd.lower().split(' ')])
    return re.findall(pattern, employee)
```

In this case we are using:
- `^` as the first character inside a `[]` (called character class), denotes any character except for those specified in the character class, e.g. `[^abc]` would match *anything* that is not `a` or `b` or `c` (so `d`, or a white space, or `@`)
- and the `?`, which means the previous symbol is optional...

So, `[^a-zA-Z0-9]?` means an optional single non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: i don't want "Tom" to be found in "Atomic". Your solution looks good. Let me understand it and i will accept it. Thanks for the explanation..that helps...teaches me how to fish!

Comment: it doesn't work in case of `check_subset_regex("ABC-xy 54!", "54 xy")`....when i do the search i am okay with special characters as they could indicate end of the sentence or end of the question etc...

Comment: @Ni_Tempe In that case it doesn't match because we haven't cleared the punctuation marks from the vendor. Would you want to clear all punctuation marks?

Comment: we can clear all special characters first. But i was wondering can we something like `"search_word=" "+search_word +"[^a-zA-Z\d:]" ` and then `str.findall(search_word)`

Comment: You mean including for the possibility of special characters at the end of the word? Sure, see EDIT2 :)

Comment: close...i updated my question to show the errors that i am getting when i am running your code