# Trying to determine if a value is part of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of AWS arns that I am iterating through.

I am trying to catch if the arn is in a list:

```
user_name = 'bluethundr'
for policy_arn in policy_arn_list:
    print("Policy ARN: ", policy_arn)
    if policy_arn == ('pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name):
        policy_exists = True
        print("Policy exists is true.")
```

But the `if` test is not catching the fact that the ARN already exists. Here is my output:

```
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-iam
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-rds
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-s3
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr
```

The ARN I am looking for is:

```
arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr
```

I can verify that that ARN exists on the cli:

```bash
aws iam list-policies --scope Local --profile=jf-dev | jq -r '.Policies[].PolicyName' | grep bluethundr
pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr
```

This is the contents of `policy_arn_list`:

```
['arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user2',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user4',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-s3',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-ec2',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-rds',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-iam',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user1',
 'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user3']
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the if test not seeing that the ARN I am looking for is already in the list?

Comment: Maybe a membership check rather than the check for equality helps..

Comment: What are the contents of policy_arn_list? You may want to use [`string.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), instead of `==`

Comment: The contents of the policy_arn_list is in the output. I am iterating through them with policy_arn.

Comment: I suggest to add the tag for amazon web service to the question, as your list is not a list of string but a list of AWS. May be relevant.

Comment: I added the contents of policy_arn_list to the OP. thanks

Comment: Based on your addition either my solution or John Gordon's should work. John's is a little more precise, while mine is more general. Just depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
if ('pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name) in str(policy_arn):
```

seems to me 1) policy_arn may not be a string (can't tell), and 2) might have more characters than just ('pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name). If either of these are the  only problems then my solution should work.

Comment: If this works it is related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Some other good solutions here too that I will look into. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Since it worked you could try this if `('pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name) in policy_arn:`, which would save you the string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
The ARN I am looking for is:
arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr
```

Your code is looking for `pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr`, but the actual ARN value has extra stuff at the beginning, and you are checking for *equality* instead of a *substring match*.

Assuming the stuff at the beginning of the string is unimportant, you can try this:

```
if policy_arn.endswith('/pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name):
```

Comment: Ok. How do I check for a substring match?

Answer (score 1):

It this case you could do by using the `str` method [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) as shown below. For more complicated patterns, you might need to use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expression module, but that doesn't seem necessary to handle something this simple.

```
policy_arn_list = ['arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user2',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user4',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-s3',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-ec2',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-rds',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-iam',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user1',
                   'arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user3']

user_name = 'bluethundr'
search_target = 'pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name
for policy_arn in policy_arn_list:
    print("Policy ARN: ", policy_arn)
#    if policy_arn == ('pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name):
    if policy_arn.endswith(search_target):
        policy_exists = True
        print("Policy exists is true.")
```

Output:

```
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user2
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user4
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr
Policy exists is true.
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-s3
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-ec2
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-rds
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-iam
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user1
Policy ARN:  arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-user3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr` is not equal to `pol-aws-secrets-manager-bluethundr`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `policy_arn` in `policy_arn in policy_arn_list` starts with `arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/`
I'd just tweak the concat syntax in the if statement to ensure right comparison.
Below is the revised code.

```
user_name = 'bluethundr'
for policy_arn in policy_arn_list:
        print("Policy ARN: ", policy_arn)
        if policy_arn == ('arn:aws:iam::849355752309:policy/'+'pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name):
            policy_exists = True
            print("Policy exists is true.")
```