# Using a keyword to print a sentence in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file

Hello I am writing a Python program that reads through a given .txt file and looks for keywords. In this program once I have found my keyword (for example `'data'`) I would like to print out the entire sentence the word is associated with.

I have read in my input file and used the `split()` method to rid of spaces, tabs and newlines and put all the words into an array.

Here is the code I have thus far.

```
text_file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = []
lines = text_file.read().split()
keyword = 'data'

for token in lines:
    if token == keyword:
         //I have found my keyword, what methods can I use to
        //print out the words before and after the keyword 
       //I have a feeling I want to use '.' as a marker for sentences
           print(sentence) //prints the entire sentence
```

`file.txt` Reads as follows

```
Welcome to SOF! This website securely stores data for the user.
```

desired output:

```
This website securely stores data for the user.
```

Comment: you can if you store/loop with the index using `enumerate` and get previous & next index. But the bigger problem is to separate the _sentences_ first

Comment: If the token occurs twice in a sentence, should you print it more than once?

Comment: @MelvinYellow Yes the word is guaranteed to be found in the text file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the enumerate method! that make iterating easier, as for separating sentences I will use a period ('.') as a marker. I just need to figure out how to detect the period in the array, since it is attached to a word.

Comment: just use `word.endswith(".")` for instance. Or regex to detect punctuation

Comment: You don't need to read the entire file into memory at once. Just iterate over the file itself: `for line in text_file: tokens = line.strip().split(); ...`.

Comment: @chepner true, but not if the sentence is on several lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just split text on characters that represent line endings and then loop trough those lines and print those who contain our keyword.

To split text on multiple characters , for example line ending can be marked with `! ? .`  we can use regex:

```
import re

keyword = "data"
line_end_chars = "!", "?", "."
example = "Welcome to SOF! This website securely stores data for the user?"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, line_end_chars))
line_list = re.split(regexPattern, example)

# line_list looks like this:
# ['Welcome to SOF', ' This website securely stores data for the user', '']

# Now we just need to see which lines have our keyword
for line in line_list:
    if keyword in line:
        print(line)
```

> But keep in mind that: `if keyword in line:` matches a sequence of
>   characters, not necessarily a whole word - for example, 'data' in
>   'datamine' is True. If you only want to match whole words, you ought
>   to use regular expressions:
>   [source explanation with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320179/11311072)

[Source for regex delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184791/11311072)

Comment: careful as `if keyword in line` also works for substrings, not whole words.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is similar to [Alberto Poljak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11311072/alberto-poljak) but a little more explicit.

The motivation is to realise that splitting on words is unnecessary - Python's `in` operator will happily find a word in a sentence. What is necessary is the splitting of sentences. Unfortunately, sentences can end with `.`, `?` or `!` and Python's `split` function does not allow multiple separators. So we have to get a little complicated and use `re`.

`re` requires us to put a `|` between each delimiter and *escape* some of them, because both `.` and `?` have special meanings by default. Alberto's solution used `re` itself to do all this, which is definitely the way to go. But if you're new to `re`, my hard-coded version might be clearer.

The other addition I made was to put each sentence's trailing delimiter back on the sentence it belongs to. To do this I wrapped the delimiters in `()`, which captures them in the output. I then used `zip` to put them back on the sentence they came from. The `0::2` and `1::2` slices will take every even index (the sentences) and concatenate them with every odd index (the delimiters). Uncomment the `print` statement to see what's happening.

```
import re

lines = "Welcome to SOF! This website securely stores data for the user. Another sentence."
keyword = "data"

sentences = re.split('(\.|!|\?)', lines)

sentences_terminated = [a + b for a,b in zip(sentences[0::2], sentences[1::2])]

# print(sentences_terminated)

for sentence in sentences_terminated:
    if keyword in sentence:
        print(sentence)
        break
```

Output:

```
 This website securely stores data for the user.
```

Comment: Upvoted because you explained parts of my answer better than me while I just pasted the source.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a fairly simple regex in order to find your keyword in a sentence, with words that may or may not be before and after it, and a final period character. It works well with spaces and it's only one execution of `re.search()`.

```
import re

text_file = open("file.txt", "r")
text = text_file.read()

keyword = 'data'

match = re.search("\s?(\w+\s)*" + keyword + "\s?(\w+\s?)*.", text)
print(match.group().strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
def check_for_stop_punctuation(token):
    stop_punctuation = ['.', '?', '!']
    for i in range(len(stop_punctuation)):
        if token.find(stop_punctuation[i]) > -1:
            return True
    return False

text_file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = []
lines = text_file.read().split()
keyword = 'data'

sentence = []
stop_punctuation = ['.', '?', '!']

i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    token = lines[i]
    sentence.append(token)
    if token == keyword:
        found_stop_punctuation = check_for_stop_punctuation(token)
        while not found_stop_punctuation:
            i += 1
            token = lines[i]
            sentence.append(token)
            found_stop_punctuation = check_for_stop_punctuation(token)
        print(sentence)
        sentence = []
    elif check_for_stop_punctuation(token):
        sentence = []
    i += 1
```