# How to check if any word of string match another string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to find some function in Python which can help me with finding some word-matches of two different strings.

For example we have 2 strings:

1. "I am playing basketball everyday"
2. "basketball is the worst game ever"

And I want this function to return true if "basketball" was found in both strings.

Comment: So what is the problem in doing so? Can we see your code?

Comment: You can always use `in`. For example, `"basketball" in "I love basketball"` returns `True`

Comment: `"basketball" in string_1 and "basketball" in string_2`

Comment: Another approach would be to use list(set(string_1.split()) & set(string_2.split())) which would return all words found in both strings

Answer (score 2):

You can find which are the common words in two phrases:

```
common_words = set(phrase1.split()).intersection(phrase2.split())
```

You can check if a word is in both phrases by simply checking if it is in the `common_words` set (example: `if word in common_words: ...`).

You can also check how many elements this set has. If `len(common_words) == 0` then `phrase1` and `phrase2` contain no common words.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["I am playing basketball everyday", "basketball is the worst game ever"]

for x in l:
  print (x)
  if "basketball" in x.lower():
    print (True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "I am playing basketball everyday"
str2 = "basketball is the worst game ever"

if "basketball" in str1 and "basketball" in str2:
    print "basketball is in both strings!"
```

See: [Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string)