# Is there a way that you can find a keyword from a string in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

```
message = "I'm new and this is new my account."
```

The program will try to detect 'hi' in this string even there is no 'hi' in here, it will found the keyword in "and t**hi**s is m..." part if try to use a code like this:

```
if "hi" in message.lower():
    print("He said hi!")
```

How can I block this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

```py
import re


message = "I'm new and this is new my account."
message_with_hi = "what's up, I'm saying hi"
pattern = r'\bhi\b'  # \b is word boundary

r = re.findall(pattern, message)
r2 = re.findall(pattern, message_with_hi)
print(r)  # prints []
print(r2)  # prints ['hi']
```

This also covers cases like `message = "I am saying hi!"`.

Comment: Tnx bro saved me

Comment: @Demir All good, please accept the answer (click the tick mark) if it solved your question.

Answer (score -1):

An elegant solution would be:

```
if ' hi ' in f' {message} ':
    print("He said hi!")
```

Or using regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320179/4585157

Comment: it can be work but what if the string starts with hi?
"hi, my name is ..."
yes, there's a space after 'hi' but no space before 'hi'

Comment: @Demir Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400389/2415524) to handle that case.

Comment: @Demir then this would still work. We add a space before and after the message for the check.