# Bot responding to channel mentions

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to develop a discord bot in python recently. I made it so that if a message contains a certain number, it will react and send a message. Here is the code in the cog file:

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
    
nice_numbers = ['69', '420']
    
class Auto(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
      
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        
        msg = message.content
    
        if message.author == self.client.user:
             return
    
        if any (word in msg for word in nice_numbers):
             await message.add_reaction('')
             await message.channel.send(f'lmao nice')
        
    
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Auto(client))
```

The problem is, the bot also responds with the same message and reaction when a user mentions a certain channel (in this case #general, #super-private-testing, and #resources). I can't seem to fix it or figure out why it's happening. I'm still pretty new to python so can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that **mentions** have a special syntax within the Discord API where they are basically a bunch of numbers put together.

For example when you are mentioning another **user** like the following:

> Hello @User1234!

The real syntax within the discord message is the following:

> Hello <@125342019199458000>!

And in the case of mentioning channels, it works similar, as a channel mentioned like:

> #general

Internally would be written as:

> <#550012071928922144>

Of course, the problem is that within this big number there could be false positive of finding your **nice_numbers**. There could be different ways to avoid this, for example you could check if a *channel* or a *user* is being mentioned in the *message* and return in that case.

```
if message.channel_mentions or message.mentions:
    return
```

I think a better solution would be to changing the way you are checking if the **nice_numbers** are within `message.content`.

Using `if word in msg` would return `true` if `message.content` also includes something like *'My favourite number is 456**69**'*. To overcome this issue it is better to make use of [**regular expressions**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

You can declare a new function like [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320179/14989571) explains, which would return a `<match object>` if what you pass as parameter is found.

It would be something like this:

```
import re

def findCoincidences(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w)).search

findCoincidences('69')('I like 69')    # -> return <match object>
findCoincidences('69')('My favourite number is 45669')                   # -> return None
```

Comment: hmm, i see. Thanks for the help! Now to fix my code...

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Shunya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822718/1208424), you can use [`message.clean_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content) instead of `message.content`:

> A property that returns the content in a “cleaned up” manner. This basically means that mentions are transformed into the way the client shows it. e.g. <#id> will transform into #name.
>
> This will also transform @everyone and @here mentions into non-mentions.

This will prevent you from inadvertently matching against the IDs of channels, users, roles, etc. Of course, if the actual name contains a `nice_number`, it'll still match.