# find function in python malfunctioning or not working, or am I missing something?

Tags: python, tkinter, find

Heyy, I'm trying to create a button that starts a script depending on what it finds in a text
sorry if this question is hard to comprehend.

the script (i will shorten it for a simpler example) :

```
import Tkinter as *
window = Tk()

#locals

Depended = 1    #this is what depends on what script it will start
Active = False  #this will start the script

#commands
def check():
    global Depended

    text = scrolltext.get("1.0", "end") #scrolltext is basically like a tkinter text

    find_AutoFishing = text.find("AutoFishing")
    find_HoldClick = text.find("HoldClick")   #what its looking for
    find_SpamClick = text.find("SpamClick")

    if find_AutoFishing:
        print("found autofish")
        Depended = 10
    elif find_HoldClick:
        print("found holdclick") #what it found
        Depended = 20
    elif find_SpamClick:
        print("found spamclick")
        Depended = 30
    else:
        print("nothing found") 

def Start():
    global Active
    check()        #this will start the script
    Active = True

    t = Thread (target=ATTACK)
    t.start()


def Stop():
    global Active
    global Depended #this will end the script
    Active = False
    Depended = 1


#scrolltext works the same as Text in Tkinter
scrolltext = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, height=11, width=60, bg="#050505", fg="white", bd=0)
scrolltext.pack()

execute_button = Button(main, command=Start)
execute_button.pack()

purge_button = Button(main, command=Stop)
purge_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

basically, the problem I'm running into is when I have the word "SpamClick" in my scrolltext
and press execute, the check function will not work and not detect that the work SpamClick was in
the scrolltext, but instead of printing "Depended = 1" it will print something like "Depended = 20".

Sorry again if this script is very hard to comprehend, don't spend too much time on the question as iI might come across a solution soon enough since this is my main project at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the problem,

when I said

```
find_AutoFishing = text.find("AutoFishing")
find_HoldClick = text.find("HoldClick")   #what its looking for
find_SpamClick = text.find("SpamClick")

if find_AutoFishing:
    print("found autofish")
    Depended = 10
elif find_HoldClick:
    print("found holdclick") #what it found
    Depended = 20
elif find_SpamClick:
    print("found spamclick")
    Depended = 30
else:
    print("nothing found")
```

what I was meant to say was:

```
if "AutoFishing in text:
    print("AutoFishing")
    Depended = 10
```

It's basically just the fact that I didn't state the function correctly, thanks anyways
anyone that's seeing this :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string

for further example