# How to perform data cleaning for a text file?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, txt

I have a text file with lots of lines, including words and numbers, here is an example:

```
2021-12-06 05:07:09.266 INFO: Additional  ID 1638301749791
2021-12-06 05:07:09.266 INFO: Found 
2021-12-06 05:07:09.267 INFO: ObjectStatus-ok factor 1163 factor five and six computed as it was before best weight ID 1638301749796
2021-12-06 05:07:09.267 INFO: disabled; computing power weight factor factor 19025.
2021-12-06 05:07:10.041 INFO: Wrote big factor 0.3568357342, Classificationfactortype-fail
2021-12-06 05:07:10.042 DEBUG: Duiu.0.0.2588650814
2021-12-06 05:07:10.743 INFO: Wrote .3254806495
```

My question is how can I keep **lines that have particular word**"Classificationfactortype-fail" and "ObjectStatus-ok", and delete all other lines? I would like to save the new text file in the directory.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
ans = []

with open('test. txt') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        line = line.strip()
        if "Classificationfactortype-fail" in line or "ObjectStatus-ok" in line:
          ans.append(line)

with open('extracted_data.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in ans:
        wf.write(line)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string)

Comment: What exaclty is not working with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each line starts with the timecode, then **str.startswith()** won't work.

You can simply do:

```
if "Classificationfactortype-fail" in line or "ObjectStatus-ok" in line:
   ans.append(line)
```

in your first loop.

Comment: Exactly. 
Also, your first statement should be `with open('test. txt', 'r') as rf`, and your `for` loop needs to be `for line in rf.readlines()`.

Comment: @MarcoCouto indeed that's good practise, but they're not strictly necessary: **open()**'s  default mode is already **"r"** and the loop through the file returns each line. But yes, it makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: It writes everything in a single line, in my new txt file. How do I make it to write separately?

Comment: What if you append a newline character when writing each line to the file?

Comment: @MarcoCouto https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html

Comment: @nikki Marco Couto is right: unlike **print()**, **file.write()** does not add a **newline** character at the end, so you have to add it manually either in the first loop `ans.append(line + "\n")` **OR** when writing the new file: `wf.write(line + "\n")`