# Along with the word, the script also searches for parts of the word

Tags: python

My script finds other words along with the word like **apple**, such as app, me, ple, appl, etc. which in the **search_word**, but i don't want it, i need the script to define only the complete word which in the **contents** but not its parts.

apple - yes, i want to define this word.
app - no, i don't want to define this word.

*list.txt contains:*

```
apple
```

code:

```
with open('list.txt') as file:
    contents = file.read()
    search_word = input("enter a word you want to search in file: ")
    if search_word in contents:
        print ('word found')
    else:
        print ('word not found')
```

this not work:

```
if search_word == contents:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check If Word Is In A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string)

Comment: @mkrieger1 The answers seem to talk about what OP is already doing...

Comment: What are `contents` and `search_word` exactly? It sounds like `contents` is something like `'apple'`, and when `search_word = 'app'`, you want it to say "word not found", but instead it says "word found". Is that right? Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] your post. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea yes! I will approve my question.

Comment: This might answer your question: [How to match a whole word with a regular expression?](/q/15863066/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if search_word in contents:
```

Just change to:

```
if any(search_word==word.strip() for word in contents.split())
```

Thanks to the contribution in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

You may split the text using the space to avoid partial matching.

```
text_list = contents.split()
if search_word in text_list:
    print ('word found')
```

Comment: That's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917839).