# One-hot encoding: list membership error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, one-hot-encoding

Given a variable number of strings, I'd like to one-hot encode them as in the following example:

```
s1 = 'awaken my love'
s2 = 'awaken the beast'
s3 = 'wake beast love'

# desired result - NumPy array
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Current code:

```
def uniquewords(*args):
    """Create order-preserved string with unique words between *args"""
    allwords = ' '.join(args).split()
    return ' '.join(sorted(set(allwords), key=allwords.index)).split()

def encode(*args):
    """One-hot encode the given input strings"""
    unique = uniquewords(*args)
    feature_vectors = np.zeros((len(args), len(unique)))
    for vec, s in zip(feature_vectors, args):
        for num, word in enumerate(unique):                
            vec[num] = word in s
    return feature_vectors
```

The issue is in this line:

```
vec[num] = word in s
```

Which picks up, for instance, `'wake' in 'awaken my love'` as `True` (rightly so, but not for my needs) and gives the following, slightly-off result:

```
print(encode(s1, s2, s3))
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

I've seen [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154961/find-substring-in-string-but-only-if-whole-words) using `re` but am not sure how to apply here.  How can I correct the one-liner above?  (Getting rid of the nested loop would be nice too, but I'm not asking for general code editing unless it's kindly offered.)

Comment: `word in s` isn't testing `'wake' in ['awaken']`. It's testing `'wake' in 'awaken'`.

Comment: (well, really `'wake' in 'awaken my love'` or `'wake' in 'awaken the beast'`)

Comment: Perform the `in` test against a string's set of words, rather than against the string.

Comment: ...what? No, you've already got logic to convert a string to a set of words. Just use it a bit differently.

Comment: I'm not talking about converting the `str` representation of a set back into a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a slight refactoring so that you treat each sentence as a list of words thoughout, it removes a lot of the `split`ting and `join`ing you're having to do, and naturalises the behaviour of `word in s` a bit. However, a `set` is preferred for membership testing, as it can do this in `O(1)`, and you should only construct one per argument iterated over, so your code would result in this:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def uniquewords(*args):
    """Create order-preserved string with unique words between *args"""
    allwords = list(itertools.chain(*args))
    return sorted(set(allwords), key=allwords.index)

def encode(*args):
    """One-hot encode the given input strings"""
    args_with_words = [arg.split() for arg in args]
    unique = uniquewords(*args_with_words)
    feature_vectors = np.zeros((len(args), len(unique)))
    for vec, s in zip(feature_vectors, args_with_words):
        s_set = set(s)
        for num, word in enumerate(unique):                
            vec[num] = word in s_set
    return feature_vectors

print encode("awaken my love", "awaken the beast", "wake beast love")
```

with the correct output of

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

Once you've done this, you might realise you don't really need membership testing at all, and you can just iterate over s, only bothering with words that need to be set to `1`. This approach may be significantly faster over larger datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def uniquewords(*args):
    """Dictionary of words to their indices in the matrix"""
    words = {}
    n = 0
    for word in itertools.chain(*args):
        if word not in words:
            words[word] = n
            n += 1
    return words

def encode(*args):
    """One-hot encode the given input strings"""
    args_with_words = [arg.split() for arg in args]
    unique = uniquewords(*args_with_words)
    feature_vectors = np.zeros((len(args), len(unique)))
    for vec, s in zip(feature_vectors, args_with_words):
        for word in s:                
            vec[unique[word]] = 1
    return feature_vectors

print encode("awaken my love", "awaken the beast", "wake beast love")
```

Comment: All answers were elegant, but I'm accepting this one because it's 4x faster than the numpy approach and also well explained.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach -

```
def membership(list_strings):
    split_str = [i.split(" ") for i in list_strings]
    split_str_unq = np.unique(np.concatenate(split_str))
    out = np.array([np.in1d(split_str_unq, b_i) for b_i in split_str]).astype(int)
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = split_str_unq)
    return df_out
```

Sample run -

```
In [189]: s1 = 'awaken my love'
     ...: s2 = 'awaken the beast'
     ...: s3 = 'wake beast love'
     ...: 

In [190]: membership([s1,s2,s3])
Out[190]: 
   awaken  beast  love  my  the  wake
0       1      0     1   1    0     0
1       1      1     0   0    1     0
2       0      1     1   0    0     1
```

Here's another making use of `np.searchsorted` to get the column indices per row for setting into the output array and hopefully faster -

```
def membership_v2(list_strings):
    split_str = [i.split(" ") for i in list_strings]
    all_strings = np.concatenate(split_str)
    split_str_unq = np.unique(all_strings)
    col = np.searchsorted(split_str_unq, all_strings)
    row = np.repeat(np.arange(len(split_str)) , [len(i) for i in split_str])
    out = np.zeros((len(split_str),col.max()+1),dtype=int)
    out[row, col] = 1
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = split_str_unq)
    return df_out
```

Note that the output as a dataframe is meant mostly for a better/easier representation of the output.

Comment: Your `v2` version is very fast indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to create a one-hot encoding transformation from a list of  lists (e.g. a list of strings where each each string is subsequently split into a list of words).

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = 'awaken my love'
s2 = 'awaken the beast'
s3 = 'wake beast love'

words = pd.Series([s1, s2, s3])
df = pd.melt(words.str.split().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
             value_name='word', id_vars='index')
result = (
    pd.concat([df['index'], pd.get_dummies(df['word'])], axis=1)
    .groupby('index')
    .any()
).astype(float)
>>> result
       awaken  beast  love  my  the  wake
index                                    
0           1      0     1   1    0     0
1           1      1     0   0    1     0
2           0      1     1   0    0     1

>>> result.values
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

**Explanation**

First, create a series from your list of words.

Then split the words into columns and reset the index:

```
>>> words.str.split().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
# Output:
#    index       0      1      2
# 0      0  awaken     my   love
# 1      1  awaken    the  beast
# 2      2    wake  beast   love
```

One then melts this intermediate dataframe above which results in the following:

```
   index variable    word
0      0        0  awaken
1      1        0  awaken
2      2        0    wake
3      0        1      my
4      1        1     the
5      2        1   beast
6      0        2    love
7      1        2   beast
8      2        2    love
```

Apply `get_dummies` to the words and concatenate the results to their index locations.  The resulting datatframe is then grouped on `index` and `any` is used on the aggregation (all values are zero or one, so `any` indicates if there are one or more instances of that word).  This returns a boolean matrix, which is converted to floats.  To return the numpy array, apply `.values` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

A Set will make the in operator runs in O(1) on average.

Change:

```
vec[num] = word in s
```

to:

```
vec[num] = word in set(s.split())
```

Final version:

```
def encode(*args):
    """One-hot encode the given input strings"""
    unique = uniquewords(*args)
    feature_vectors = np.zeros((len(args), len(unique)))
    for vec, s in zip(feature_vectors, args):
        for num, word in enumerate(unique):
            vec[num] = word in set(s.split())
    return feature_vectors
```

Result:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

Comment: Strings are splitted on whitespace by default: `word in s.split()`

Comment: changed. although explicit is better than implicit :)

Comment: Not sure that applies here. Readability should *always* take precedence. The latter is more readable.