# How to count exactly a word in string in python3?

Tags: python, count

So I want to count exactly the number of appearances of "100" in python.
My example code:

```
a = " I love 1000 and 100 dollars."
b = a.count("100")
print(b)
```

The result is 2 but I just want it is 1.

```
2
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Is there any basic tip for that?
I'm just a beginner learn python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count substrings within the string, the Regular Expression module, `re`, would be useful:

```
import re
len(re.findall(r'\b100\b', a)) # prints 1
```

`len` returning the count of how many occurrences `re.findall()` finds, i.e. `1`.

Replace the `100` with the specific substring you wish to count:

```
b = len(re.findall(r'\bI love\b', a))
>>> b
1
```

technique borrowed from this answer [Find substring in string but only if whole words?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155064/1248974)

Answer (score 1):

```
" I love 1000 and 100 dollars.".split().count('100')
```

FYI, below is a convenient and efficient way of counting every word.

```
from collections import Counter

Counter("I love 1000 and 100 dollars.".split())

# result: Counter({'I': 1, 'love': 1, '1000': 1, 'and': 1, '100': 1, 'dollars.': 1})
```

Comment: @ĐăngBùi wants to return 1. Without `split()` the result would be 2.

Comment: @davedwards, the OP was looking for `100` not `1000`. the results are different in this case

Comment: Strings are iterators (like lists) themselves already and just count would work the same way though. count('100') instead of count('1000') would obviously return 2

Comment: @davedwards sorry I made a typo, it should be `count('100')`.

Comment: I think @gdlmx show my sastisfied answer. However is there any way to count directly in  `str` objects?

Comment: If we use object `list` to count, I can count string like this `"I love"`. If I use `split()` , the result of `" I love 1000 and 100 dollars.".split().count('I love')` will be `0`. :(